# Use Spring Integration to move File Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, sftp

We're using Spring 4.3.3.Release and Spring Integration 4.3.4.Release which should both be the latest versions as of the time of this post.   We're creating a File object in the application, and we don't need to write this file out to disk.

We want to take the File object and using Spring Integration, move this file to a remote SFTP directory.

I have some familiarity with Spring Integration, and I have been looking at some of the examples, and I am not sure which example makes the most sense right now.

If I could be referred to the right place, then I will take the examples and see how I can apply them to my code.

Thanks!

UPDATE 1:

Here is my new application context XML file:

```
<int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutbondAdapter" 
    channel="ftpOutboundChannel"
    remote-directory="${sftp.remote.outbound.dir}" 
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" >
    <int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:retry-advice />
    </int-sftp:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ftpOutboundChannel"/>
```

The "sftp.remote.outbound.dir" is to a real directory on the sftp server:
/home/test/tom/outbound

And my class looks something like:

```
@Transactional
@Service("reportService")
public class ReportServiceImpl implements ReportService
{
    @Autowired
    private MessageChannel ftpOutboundChannel;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${sftp.timerTaskCron}", zone = "UTC")
    public void runReports() throws Exception
    {
          File file = new File(path to some local filename);
          // yes, this file really exists

          Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
          ftpOutboundChannel.send(message);
          // I presume this file is output to that local directory
    }
}
```

This seems to compile ok, but I just want to make sure the mechanism to move this is configured correctly.

I have a unit test that is very similar.  It's Transactional, and maybe it shouldn't be?

```
public class SftpOutboundReceiveSample extends BaseServiceTests
{
@Autowired
private MessageChannel ftpOutboundChannel;

private String _filename = "/src/test/resources/attachment/DemoTrialFormv6_1.pdf";

@Test
public void runDemo()
{
    File file = new File(_filename);
    assertNotNull(file);
    Message<File> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(file).build();
    ftpOutboundChannel.send(message);
 }
}
```

Does the fact that this is transactional means that it rolls the file out of this directory once we are done with the test?   Or, is this not a great test?
I am trying to just make sure that the file gets to the right location.

Answer (score 2):

In a general case it boils done to configuring proper inbound and outban channels and adapters. Something along the lines of following

```
<int:channel id="fileInboundChannel"/>
<int:channel id="ftpOutboundChannel"/>

<int:bridge input-channel="fileInboundChannel" output-channel="ftpOutboundChannel"/>

<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="fileSource"
   directory="/path/to/file" channel="fileInboundChannel"  prevent-duplicates="true">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<ftp:outbound-channel-adapter channel="ftpOutboundChannel"
   remote-directory="/path/to/storage/" session-factory="ftpSessionFactory"/>

<bean name="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.DefaultFtpSessionFactory">
    <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    <property name="port" value="587"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: No real need for the bridge in this case, you can just use the same channel on the inbound and outbound adapters. If you want to add error handling, add an `error-channel` to the poller and you'll get error messages with the payload having the failed message and cause. Also see the new `file-split-ftp` [sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/file-split-ftp) for a more sophisticated version, using the Java DSL.

Comment: Ok, so, with adding the sftpOutBoundChannel, now I need how to use that in my code.   I'll take a look at the Spring Integration examples and see how the code needs to be defined.